# Docker push intermittent failure to private docker registry on kubernetes (docker-desktop)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, registry, private, docker-desktop

I'm running a kubernetes cluster on docker-desktop (mac).

It has a local docker registry inside it.

I'm able to query the registry no problem via the API calls to get the list of tags.

I was able to push an image before, but it took multiple attempts to push.

I can't push new changes now. It looks like it pushes successfully for layers, but then doesn't acknowledge the layer has been pushed and then retries.

Repo is called localhost:5000 and I am correctly port forwarding as per instructions on https://blog.hasura.io/sharing-a-local-registry-for-minikube-37c7240d0615/

I'm ot using ssl certs as this is for development on local machine.

(The port forwarding is proven to work otherwise API call would fail)

```
e086a4af6e6b: Retrying in 1 second 
35c20f26d188: Layer already exists 
c3fe59dd9556: Pushing [========================>                          ]  169.3MB/351.5MB
6ed1a81ba5b6: Layer already exists 
a3483ce177ce: Retrying in 16 seconds 
ce6c8756685b: Layer already exists 
30339f20ced0: Retrying in 1 second 
0eb22bfb707d: Pushing [==================================================>]  45.18MB
a2ae92ffcd29: Waiting 
received unexpected HTTP status: 502 Bad Gateway
```

*workaround (this will suffice but not ideal, as have to build each container*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: producer
  namespace: aetasa
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kafkaproducer
    image: localhost:5000/aetasa/cta-user-create-app
    imagePullPolicy: Never // this line uses the built container in docker
    ports:
        - containerPort: 5005
```

Kubectl logs for registry

```
10.1.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2019:19:18:03 +0000] "POST /v2/aetasa/cta-user-create-app/blobs/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 202 0 "-" "docker/18.09.2 go/go1.10.6 git-commit/6247962 kernel/4.9.125-linuxkit os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.09.2 \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"
2019/02/20 19:18:03 [warn] 12#12: *293 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000011, client: 10.1.0.1, server: localhost, request: "PATCH /v2/aetasa/cta-user-create-app/blobs/uploads/16ad0e41-9af3-48c8-bdbe-e19e2b478278?_state=qjngrtaLCTal-7-hLwL9mvkmhOTHu4xvOv12gxYfgPx7Ik5hbWUiOiJhZXRhc2EvY3RhLXVzZXItY3JlYXRlLWFwcCIsIlVVSUQiOiIxNmFkMGU0MS05YWYzLTQ4YzgtYmRiZS1lMTllMmI0NzgyNzgiLCJPZmZzZXQiOjAsIlN0YXJ0ZWRBdCI6IjIwMTktMDItMjBUMTk6MTg6MDMuMTU2ODYxNloifQ%3D%3D HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:5000"
2019/02/20 19:18:03 [error] 12#12: *293 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.1.0.1, server: localhost, request: "PATCH /v2/aetasa/cta-user-create-app/blobs/uploads/16ad0e41-9af3-48c8-bdbe-e19e2b478278?_state=qjngrtaLCTal-7-hLwL9mvkmhOTHu4xvOv12gxYfgPx7Ik5hbWUiOiJhZXRhc2EvY3RhLXVzZXItY3JlYXRlLWFwcCIsIlVVSUQiOiIxNmFkMGU0MS05YWYzLTQ4YzgtYmRiZS1lMTllMmI0NzgyNzgiLCJPZmZzZXQiOjAsIlN0YXJ0ZWRBdCI6IjIwMTktMDItMjBUMTk6MTg6MDMuMTU2ODYxNloifQ%3D%3D HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.104.68.90:5000/v2/aetasa/cta-user-create-app/blobs/uploads/16ad0e41-9af3-48c8-bdbe-e19e2b478278?_state=qjngrtaLCTal-7-hLwL9mvkmhOTHu4xvOv12gxYfgPx7Ik5hbWUiOiJhZXRhc2EvY3RhLXVzZXItY3JlYXRlLWFwcCIsIlVVSUQiOiIxNmFkMGU0MS05YWYzLTQ4YzgtYmRiZS1lMTllMmI0NzgyNzgiLCJPZmZzZXQiOjAsIlN0YXJ0ZWRBdCI6IjIwMTktMDItMjBUMTk6MTg6MDMuMTU2ODYxNloifQ%3D%3D", host: "localhost:5000"
```

Comment: Please share the command used to push onto docker registry. Also , is the register within kubernetes or just as plain docker container. Also share the ```kubectl get po``` for registry if it is part of kubernetes or ```docker ps``` otherwise

Comment: Could you please also share logs from the registry pod/container?

Comment: Previously I had seen an error "blob" unknown, however it doesn't seem to appear anymore.

Comment: @fatcook the registry is inside the kube cluster

Comment: Can you try this if you have not already done that , set the ```--insecure-registries``` flag in docker config to localhost:5000 , details on how that can be done is present [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/)

Comment: Insecure registries is already on. When I query the registry, the image is listed, but some of the layers are missing.

Comment: Try configure `--max-concurrent-uploads=1` for your docker client. You are pushing quite large layers (350MB), so probably you are hitting some limits (request sizes, timeouts) somewhere. Single concurrent upload may help you.

Comment: @JanGaraj If you can post a answer with clear instructions as to how to do that and it works, you will be given the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Try configure `--max-concurrent-uploads=1` for your docker client. You are pushing quite large layers (350MB), so probably you are hitting some limits (request sizes, timeouts) somewhere. Single concurrent upload may help you, but it is only a work around. Real solution will be configuration (buffer sizes, timeouts, ...) of registry + reverse proxy in front of registry eventually.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a disk space issue. If you store docker images inside the Docker VM you can fill up the disk space quite fast.

By default, docker-desktop VM disk space is limited to 64 gigabytes. You can increase it up to 112Gb on the "**Disk**" tab in Docker **Preferences**.

Comment: That's not it. Disk preferences says VM is only 15.7GB on disk.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issues quite few times and unfortunately couldn't get to the permanent fix.

Most likely the image should have been corrupted in the registry. As a work around, i suggest you delete the image from registry and do a fresh push. it would work and subsequent pushes would work too.

This issue must be related to the missing layers of the image. sometimes we delete the image using --force option, in that case it is possible that some of the common layers might get deleted and would affect other images that share the deleted layers.